# gnome subtitles "could not play the file"

Tags: video, gstreamer

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 with Gnome-subtitles 1.6 installed via PPA as follows

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pedrocastro/ppa 
sudo apt-get update sudo
apt-get install gnome-subtitles
```

because they are not in Ubuntu 18.04 anymore.

Sometimes Gnome Subtitles says "could not play the file" followed by "Gstreamer error" (two times successively) when opening the *.srt subtitle, while most of the time it is able to open all video formats.
It detects the presence of the video (mp4, mkv, avi formats) and can't play the video.
I've tried different permission combination in order to exclude that issue.
I have also updated Gstreamer with following commands :

```
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkgsudo 
apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

[edit : output of `dpkg -l | grep gstreamer`]

```
$ dpkg -l | grep gstreamer
ii  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:amd64                    1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GObject introspection data for the GStreamer library
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                       1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0:amd64                3.0.26-1                                        amd64        Clutter PLugin for GStreamer 1.0
ii  gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3:amd64                0.10.32.debian-1                                amd64        Fluendo mp3 decoder GStreamer 1.0 plugin
ii  gstreamer1.0-gl:amd64                         1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer plugins for GL
ii  gstreamer1.0-gtk3:amd64                       1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer plugin for GTK+3
ii  gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64                      1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        libav plugin for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-packagekit                       1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5                          amd64        GStreamer plugin to install codecs using PackageKit
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64                1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64               1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps                1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer helper programs from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64               1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64               1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64                 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-tools                            1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        Tools for use with GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-vaapi:amd64                      1.14.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1                   amd64        VA-API plugins for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-x:amd64                          1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
ii  libgstreamer-gl1.0-0:amd64                    1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer GL libraries
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64           1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "bad" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64          1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64          1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "good" set
ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64                       1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer         1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10                       amd64        GStreamer backend for LibreOffice
```

Why would Gnome-Subtitles not be able to open some videos while all other video players are working (VLC, TOTEM, MPV, etc.) ? Would this be specific to the files themselves ?

Comment: `apt-cache policy gnome-subtitles`  in bionic "normal" sources not available (according to package search).And `dpkg -l | grep gstreamer` Please. Edit your Question for output.